# Move data in 3 cells/3 Columns to adjacent columns with Full Year monthly headers based on short date in column AA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an existing macro that populates expense data into three adjacent cells in columns K-M (for ~300 rows) and I want to copy the data in these cells (same order) and paste special values based on the month value of a short date that is located in column AA.  The copied data needs to be pasted into the same row as source, but columns N-Y (headers = Jan, Feb, March, Apr...Dec).  Is there code to do this?

[example below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtoiL.png)

```
Column| K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z | AA |
Header| $ | $ | $ | J | F | M | A | M | J | J | A | S | O | N | D |FY |Date|
Row 3 |978|540|395|-->|-->|978|540|395|   |   |   |   |   |   |  |1913|5/11|
Row 4 |841|779|120|-->|-->|-->|-->|841|779|120|   |   |   |   |  |1740|7/24|
Row 5 |682|557| 55|-->|-->|-->|-->|-->|-->|682|557| 55|   |   |  |1294|9/18|                    '   Row 6 |985|883|578|-->|-->|-->|-->|-->|-->|-->|-->|->|985|883|578|2446|12/2|
```

Comment: You should post an example spreadsheet or something to illustrate the desired behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've not earned the right to post an image yet....

Comment: You could use the formatting tools to create tables with example data. I believe stack overflow uses markdown.

Comment: Data in columns K-M comes from a Mainframe and cannot be easily changed.  Looking for code to move to appropriate month (columns N-Y) based on month value for date in column AA as the final month and the preceding values are placed preceding the final month as seen in example above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub MoveData()
    Dim vals As Range, val As Range, colOffset As Integer

    Set vals = Range("K2:K" & Range("K2").End(xlDown).Row)

    For Each val In vals
        If val > 0 Then
            colOffset = VBA.month(val.offset(0, 16))
            val.offset(0, colOffset) = val
            val.offset(0, colOffset + 1) = val.offset(0, 1)
            val.offset(0, colOffset + 2) = val.offset(0, 2)
        End if
    Next val
End Sub
```

Comment: It works great, but on rows that have no expense data it populates columns W-Y (Oct-Dec) all the way down these column?

Comment: See my updated code - this will only now populate data if there is expense data in column K

Comment: Columns K-M have "$0" in them as default and it is picking this up and populating in columns W-Y (Oct-Dec), but not in N-V.  Is there a way to leave columns "N-Y" blank if not >$0 and can the Macro run immediately?

Comment: See my edited code - only populates data if value is greater than $0.

Comment: Works perfectly - Thank you!